# How to do debug a running java process in linux?

Tags: linux, radare2, debuggers, java, disassemblers

**TLDR** I want to do live debugging of a java program on a linux machine, and don't how/what debugger to attach to the JVM to get this done.

I expect that this is a well-solved problem, but I lack the terminology to find a solution after several hours of searching:

I have a java program (stored in a jar file) that I'd like to observe (reverse engineer?) it *while* it runs. I see a lot of *decompilation* support for java - this isn't what I'm interested in at all, so please refrain from explaining how to do this. A major problem I'm having in my search is running into these kinds of answer.

Ideally, I'd:

1. Start the program and find the PID.
2. Attach a debugger to the JVM somehow (this is what I don't know how to do, and lack the language to search for, apparently)
3. Use the debugger to set breakpoints, read/write arbitrary memory of the JVM, see the JVM's registers and stack.
4. Use a simple, open-source command-line tool to do this, like Radare2 or GDB.

I expect to be reading java bytecode (the instruction set for the JVM), not java source, while I do this.

I am used to using Radare2 and GDB for native code (crackmes, CTF stuff, microcorruption). I also see that they both technically support Java, but I'm having a hard time figuring out *how* to do this, exactly.

I need help with 2 things: **what software to use** and **how to attach the program to the process**. Bonus points if I can use radare!

To be clear, the Java in question is running on a linux PC, not on an Android phone or anything like that.

I also read about JDB, but it seems like the code needs to be compiled with debug flags, and this is not possible for my situation -- it also doesn't seem like what I'm looking for.

Comment: This isn't a lightweight solution but would you consider adding the jar to an IDE like IntelliJ and use the debugger from there? I tested it out on a small app and it worked [just fine](https://i.imgur.com/BtiewnP.png).

Answer (score 3):

You can use jdb to attach to a running program without having compiled it with debug flags.

on my machine with jdb located at /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/jdb
and pid of my running java process = 14476

```
sudo /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/jdb -connect sun.jvm.hotspot.jdi.SAPIDAttachingConnector:pid=14476
```

However if you did not compile your program with debugging information it is going to make debugging much harder i think.

see this [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr011.html#BABFHHEE) for more info.

EDIT: i also found i can view variable values of a running process easily with jvisualvm wich is a tool that comes with oracles jdk.

1) start jvisualvm from the command line. It is located in your jdk bin folder.

```
/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/jvisualvm
```

2) on the right side of the screen you can see the running java processes on your machine. You can then perform a heap dump (right click on process) and view the values of the variables of the classes your interested in.

[image: heapdump]

Answer (score 0):

I found I also need to install one more package for the jdb attach to succeed.

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-dbg